# JavaScript Array Object Value Update (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Hi I'm trying to update row value in a table ( React Ant Ui) and it works when I use static data . For example my static data table data is

```
[
    {
      "questionNumber": "",
      "questionType": "",
      "marks": "",
      "numberOfOptions": "",
      "correctOptions": "",
    },
    {
      "questionNumber": "",
      "questionType": "",
      "marks": "",
      "numberOfOptions": "",
      "correctOptions": "",
    },
  ]
```

And I used the following method to update row data-

```
  const onInputChange: any = (key, index) => (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    const newData = [...tableData];
    newData[index][key] = (e);
    setTableData(newData);
  };
```

And if I want to update marks of `index 1` it works perfectly fine. But I need to update dynamic data. I followed this approach

```
const [tableData, setTableData] = useState<any>([]);
```

and on a button click I pushed a dynamic array value to table data like this way

```
setTableData(Array(3).fill(newObj))
```

where `newObj` value is

```
  const newObj = {
      "questionNumber": "",
      "questionType": "",
      "marks": "",
      "numberOfOptions": "",
      "correctOptions": "",
    }
```

But now I am facing a problem, if I want to change value of `marks` , it updates all index of `marks`

How can I update single index value of this dynamic array like static array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deep-cloning the objects array.

JavaScript objects are references. So the `newObj` was referenced by each slot of the array.

```js
setTableData(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Array(3).fill(newObj))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing the whole tableData state, pls try updating only what is changed in the tableData state reference directly.

```
const newData = Array(3).fill(newObj)
setTableData({... tableData, ...newData});
```